# How to connect an LED driver to an Arduino

Tags: arduino, mosfet, pwm, led-driver

How do I connect two of these [SCT2024](http://www.starchips.com.tw/pdf/datasheet/SCT2024V01_03.pdf) LED drivers to an Arduino?

This is what I have so far: I'm connecting each output to an N-channel MOSFET. I'm not sure about the other pins from the datasheet.

[image]

Comment: Electrically you'd probably just connect them to any two GPIOs, and then bit-bang in software.  Details of that amount to "do my project for me" and so don't fit the mission of this site.  But you seem a bit confused about this part, it's meant to *directly* drive LEDs, so you wouldn't use it with external FETs.  If you need external FETs to handle the current, you probably want a different chip to control them. If this is all over your head, you probably want to chose a part for which there is example code, for example look at the various LED drive solutions Adafruit integrates and supports.

Comment: Ok, what other chips supports PWM dimming? adafruit has examples using TI chips which are very expensive compared to this one and hard to get where im buying from. Ive read somewhere that I can use this library https://timodenk.com/blog/shiftregister-pwm-library/ and shift registers but that's software based and will be slow, so is bit banging. That's why I chose a cheap LED driver to control 32 outputs with PWM. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why 12V?  How many LEDs are being driven with each output?  This chip has thermal issues.  You need to use as low a voltage as possible.

Comment: @Chris comments are not for answers.

Comment: @Passerby I did not provide an *answer*, I explained what was wrong with the question and suggested things the asker might research.  Or do you consider "pick two pins and the rest is software" an answer ;-)  Perhaps if you can delegate writing it to being someone else's problem...

Answer (score 0):

Connect up to SCK, MOSI, and a pin for Latch. I wouldn't use SS in this case due to the load/ pin wanting to be low most of the time.
To send in data:

```
SPI.transfer(byte1);
SPI.transfer(byte2);
digitalWrite (load, HIGH); // latches the data
digitalWrite (load, LOW); // updates the output register
```

OE/ connects to Gnd unless, or a PWM pin for brightness control.

```
analogWrite (PWMpin, 10);  // lower for brighter, higher for dimmer
```

Comment: Send out 4 bytes for 2 chips.